# How to create tuples based on conditions in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following class:

```
case class Person(
                   firstName: String = "",
                   lastName: String = "",
                   age: Int = 1,
                   ssnr: Int = 1
                 )
```

I want to create tuples that include `firstName` and/or `lastName` only if their values are not empty.

Of course I could do the following:

`if (!person.firstName.isEmpty && !person.lastName.isEmpty)
    ("firstname" -> person.firstName, "lastName" -> person.lastName, "age" -> person.age, "ssnr" -> person.ssnr)`

But that would complicate things because I have to check several cases if `firstName` is empty or `lastName` is empty and include or exclude them on these certain preconditions (also I do have more attributes than these two).

Is there a better way than if/else conditions to deal with that?

Comment: How you will use result?

Comment: I will use that for parameters in `def withQueryString(parameters: (String, String)*): WSRequest`. Including or excluding them depending if the value is non empty or not.

Comment: I think you can either use stronger types or some re-useable functions in the companion object and that would do the trick. Depending on your use of this code etc what you have is very readable and clear so on one hand it might be something to think about again depending on many external factors.

Comment: To answer your question at face value, I would probably say something like, use Shapeless to build `HList`s (which are tuples) of different arities. But to solve your actual problem, you should probably model `Person` with a required ID field and optional name, age and SSN fields, and give it a method (say `toQueryParams`) that outputs a `Seq[(String, String)]` containing all the `Person` fields which are defined.

Answer (score 0):

You should overload the constructor. The default case class (maybe you could go for a normal class) constructor has no default values while the constructors defined in the companion object may have only one default or both.

The other, more idiomatic option, is to set those fields as `Option[String]` so that the caller can specify None when they want to omit that value.

I believe the second is a better option (ah!) but you should know how to handle it: an `Option` is a semantically stronger approach to the modeling of your data and it comes with a lot of implications, while the first java-like option is just a predefined set of ways you can build your class with.